# Adding products to an object with while loops

Tags: java, class

So i'm trying to up to 3 products in my 2 possible depot objects that the user can create.

I currently have 3 possible scenarios if

depot1 exists but 2 doesn't.

depot1 doesn't exist, but 2 does. and if they both exist.

Is there an easier way to do this? because if I only create 2 products and break out of the switch then go back in to create another it'll just overlay the already existing products.

Ive added my main class and depot class

I've tried doing perhaps a counter within a for loop to count the products being made, but I couldnt get it working.

```
if (depot1 != null && depot2 == null){
                      System.out.println("(1) " +depot1.getDepotName());
                      System.out.println("(2) Exit to menu");
                      option = console.nextInt();

                     switch (option) {

                         case 1:
                         if (depot1.checkFull() == true){
                             System.out.println("You may only have 3 products in one depot at a time");
                            break;
                        }

                            while(depot1.checkFull() == false && product1 == null){
                                System.out.println("Input the product name you'd like to add");
                                n = console.next().toLowerCase();
                                System.out.println("Input the price of product");   
                                p = console.nextInt();
                                    while (p < 0){
                                        System.out.println("Price needs to be positive");   
                                        p = console.nextInt();
                                    }
                                System.out.println("Input weight of product");
                                w = console.nextInt();
                                    while (w < 0){
                                     System.out.println("Weight needs to be positive");
                                     w = console.nextInt();
                                    }
                                System.out.println("Enter quantity of product");
                                quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();
                                    while (quantityOnHand < 0){
                                     System.out.println("Quantity must be positive");
                                     quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();                                        
                                    }                                
                                depot1.addProduct1(n, p, w, quantityOnHand);  
                                System.out.println("Would you like to add another product (y) or (n)");
                                op = console.next().toLowerCase();

                                      while (!op.equals("n") && depot1.checkFull() == false){
                                        System.out.println("Input the product you'd like to add");
                                        n = console.next().toLowerCase();
                                        System.out.println("Input the price of product");
                                        p = console.nextInt();
                                          while (p < 0){
                                            System.out.println("Price needs to be positive");   
                                            p = console.nextInt();
                                          }
                                        System.out.println("Input weight of product");
                                        w = console.nextInt();
                                          while (w < 0){
                                            System.out.println("Weight needs to be positive");
                                            w = console.nextInt();
                                          }
                                        System.out.println("Enter quantity of product");
                                        quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();
                                          while (quantityOnHand < 0){
                                          System.out.println("Quantity must be positive");
                                          quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();                                        
                                         } 
                                        depot1.addProduct2(n,p,w,quantityOnHand);

                                        System.out.println("Would you like to add another product (y) or (n)");
                                        op = console.next().toLowerCase();
                                           while(!op.equals("n") && depot1.checkFull() == false){
                                            System.out.println("Input the product you'd like to add");
                                            n = console.next().toLowerCase();
                                            System.out.println("Input the price of product");
                                            p = console.nextInt();
                                                while (p < 0){
                                                    System.out.println("Price needs to be positive");   
                                                    p = console.nextInt();
                                                }

                                             System.out.println("Input weight of product");
                                             w = console.nextInt();
                                                while (w < 0){
                                                   System.out.println("Weight needs to be positive");
                                                   w = console.nextInt();
                                                }

                                            System.out.println("Enter quantity of product");
                                            quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();
                                                while (quantityOnHand < 0){
                                                    System.out.println("Quantity must be positive");
                                                    quantityOnHand = console.nextInt();                                        
                                                } 

                                            depot1.addProduct3(n,p,w,quantityOnHand);
                                                if (depot1.checkFull() == true){
                                                    System.out.println("Your depot " +depot1.getDepotName() + " is full");
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    break;                                                  
                                                }
                                          }

                                    }
                                break;
```

```
// Checks to see if there is more than 3 products within the depot
   public boolean checkFull(){
     if(product3.getName() == "" && product3.getPrice() == 0 && product3.getQuantityOnHand() == 0)
     return false;
     else{
         return true;
        }
    }

   public void addProduct1(String n, double p,double w,int quantityOnHand){
       product1.setName(n);
       product1.setWeight(w);
       product1.setPrice(p);
       product1.setQuantity(quantityOnHand);

    }

   public void addProduct2(String n, double p,double w,int quantityOnHand){
       product2.setName(n);
       product2.setWeight(w);
       product2.setPrice(p);
       product2.setQuantity(quantityOnHand);

    }


   public void addProduct3(String n, double p,double w,int quantityOnHand){
       product3.setName(n);
       product3.setWeight(w);
       product3.setPrice(p);
       product3.setQuantity(quantityOnHand);

    }
```

Comment: so you want to add items into depot1 until you reached 3 items, then create depot2 to add 3 more items in it?

Comment: In the start of the program they can create up to 2 depots. So I had those if statements to cover if they had only made 1, or if they had made 2 but deleted depot1

Comment: so everytime the user adds an item, they get to select which depot to store it?

Comment: that was were I was going with that yeah.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something along this line

```
while (!depotIsFull()){  
    bool useDepot1 = depot1!=null && depot1.size()<3;
    bool useDepot2 = depot2!=null && depot2.size()<3;

    if(useDepot1 && useDepot2){
         int depotToUse = promptUserForDepotToUse();
         switch (depotToUse)
            case 1: addItem(depot1); break; 
            case 2: addItem(depot2); break;
            default: break; //do nothing and prompt again.
    }else if(useDepot1){ addItem( depot1); }
    else if(useDepot2 {addItem (depot2); }  

    bool userSayExit = getUserExitPrompt();
    if (userSayExit) { break; } //exit from the loop
}
```

where depotIsFull() method will check if the depots are null or already full.
addItem(Depot depot) method takes in a depot argument, and proceeds to add an item into it.
getUserExitPrompt() method will prompt the user if they wanna add another item or exit.

the idea is to move the codes for the logic away from the main loop, making it easier to read, and reuse the codes in addItem() method for both depot1 and depot2

Comment: I changed my above code to instead of creating separate products to just move the previous product up.
So product 1 is entered, once they enter the second it just puts product 2 into 1.